# Can't create the correct filter for my elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I've a problem to set the correct filter. My query looks like this:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "query_string" : {
                        "query" : "example~",
                        "analyzer" : "standard",
                        "default_operator" : "OR",
                        "fuzziness" : "AUTO"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term" : {
                        "client" : {
                            "value" : "MyClient",
                            "boost" : 1
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range" : {
                        "dateCreate" : {
                            "gte" : "2016-01-01T00:00:00+0200",
                            "lte" : "2016-12-31T23:59:59+0200"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "lang" : "php OR java"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size" : 10,
    "from" : 0,
    "sort" : [
        {
            "_score" : {
                "order" : "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The "lang" field is of type text.
My expectation is to get all documents with the given query string and then I want select only the documents which have "PHP" or "Java" in their lang field. The lang fields only contain either "PHP" or "Java" but never both strings so I thought about using an exact matching but I can't got it to work.
The result is actually a list of two documents but with total_count=2510.

One of my documents that doesn't match:

```
{
  "id" : "d3295f18-a033-4934-941a-21a8bef901e8",
  "client" : "MyClient",
  "lang" : "PHP",
  "author" : null,
  "dateCreate" : "2016-03-31T00:00:00+0200",
  "title" : "Sample document",
  "content" : "This is a short text describing the deocument."
}
```

Comment: what happens if you remove the `OR`?

Comment: Exactly the same: I'm getting two results but there have to be about 2,000 documents to list.

Comment: Can you show a sample document that should match but doesn't and also the mapping of your document?

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: Is the `client` field also of `text` type?

Comment: What happens if you only use the `match` query for the `lang` field? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, the client field is also of type text. Only the dateCreate field is of type date. And yes, the match query as single query works.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, the client field is also of type text.

`client` field must be either of `keyword` type to use term query or change the query for client from `term` to `match`:

```
{
    "match" : {
        "client" : {
            "query" : "MyClient",
            "boost" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What I would do - if single match for `lang` field works, then I would try to combine it first with `range` query, than with `term` etc. to find out which one/which combination causes the problem. You can also show us the mapping and show the document that is properly returned with your query - it will be much easier to recreate the issue.